# How to reshape array which doesn't have column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have one array which shape is (6000,) and now I want to convert it to (6000,1) to use it further. How can I do it?

```
   print("TrainX", str(trainX.T.shape))
   np.reshape(trainY, (1, trainY.shape[0]))
   print("TrainY", str(trainY.shape))
```

Both giving same output (6000,)

Comment: reshape does not act in-place.  READ the docs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1,2,3))
b = np.array([a]).T

print(np.shape(a))
print(np.shape(b))
```

Output:

```
(3,)
(3, 1)
```

Comment: What an interesting way to do it. At least pass in `copy=False`